# Prolog creating list with consecutive numbers

Tags: list, prolog

I'm newbie in Prolog and I've tried to create a list. For example when I write mazeCreator(3,List).  I want to push every number  like 1/1,1/2,1/3,2/1,2/2,2/3,3/1,3/2,3/3 in a list.To do this, I wrote a predicate but It does not work, Is there anyone who can help me ? Thanks in advance!.

```
mazeCreator(Number,[List]):-
    Number1 is Number-1,
    mazeCreator(Number1,[Number / 1|List]).
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a service predicate that takes your Number and construct a list from 1 to that.
Then recurse, incrementing a counter from 1 to Number, calling the service predicate and appending the result.

```
mazeCreator(Number, List) :-
  mazeCreator(1, Number, [], List).

mazeCreator(Index, Number, Built, List) :-
  Index =< Number,  % don't forget the check the limit
  make_list(Index, Number, Temp), % call service predicate
  append(Built, Temp, Other),
  % increment Index and recurse
  ...

% dont' forget the base case (i.e. when Index is not =< Number, equate Built and List)
mazeCreator(_, _, ....).
```

If your Prolog has between/3 and findall/3, you can do in this compact way:

```
mazeCreator(Number, List):-
  findall(I/J, (between(1, Number, I), between(1, Number, J)), List).
```

Comment: do you have an e-mail ? I've really trouble with some sort of prolog code and need your help :(

Comment: here is mine if you dont want to write yourselfs, maurobrand92@gmail.com, if you can contanct with me , I'm really be greathful.

Comment: mazeCreator(Number, List):-
  findall(I/J, (between(1, Number, I), between(1, Number, J)), List). Is works but here is the output List = [1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 2/1, 2/2, 2/3, 3/1, 3/2, ... / ...]. how should I delete the [.../...]and add 3/3 in the list ?

Comment: the List actually has all required members, try for instance `?- mazeCreator(3, List),maplist(writeln, List).`

Comment: yea I tried but I need to the list which contains only 1/1,1/2,1/3,2/1,2/2,2/3,3/1,3/2,3/3 for this example.. not [.../...]

Comment: the List is correct. What usage is missing ? You can pass to any other predicate, like - for instance - maplist.